# Phaser Open Sans not displaying the whole letter

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I am trying to type a cyrillic letter "Й" but when the letter is **on the first row** it displays as "И", without the upper part. This doesn't happen when the letter is on the second or w/e row other than the **first**.

Comment: What's the smallest example code you can provide to show this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but your question doesn't provide the elements to be acceptable, I suggest you to edit your question with at least a code snippet to replicate your problem;
*So take this aswer as a long comment please.*
In the executable snippet below you can try a basic setup to your scanario, and seems that it works.

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, '', { create: create });
function create() {
    var style = { font: "65px Open Sans", fill: "#ff0044" };
    var text = game.add.text(0, 0, "ЙАБВГДЕЖЅ\nꙀІКЛМНОПРС\nТОУФХѠЦЧШ\nЩЪЪІЬѢꙖѤЮ\nѪѬѦѨѮѰ ѲѴҀ", style);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/2.6.2/phaser.min.js"></script>
```